# What is the meaning of clockwise/counter clockwise spin of firefox progressbar in tab

Tags: firefox, progress, direction

While working on web application development on my local machine, I see that when I hit a local URL, for quite some time, Firefox progress bar spins counter clockwise, then after some it changes to clockwise rotation and the page loads. What is the meaning behind these directions? What are the evens that trigger the change in this rotation? This has kept me curious for quite some time now.

Answer (score 3):

While you're connecting to the server and the server is thinking, you get it colored grey and spinning counter-clockwise. Once the server has begun the download process (which also might involve some thinking) it changes color and spins clockwise.

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/910817